# Android Google Maps OnInfoWindowClick keep icon from clicked marker

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to use the icon from the markers I click in an AlertDialog. For title its .getTitle() but is there a similar way to do this for icons? (I have another method with a bunch of if statements but it is sloppy work)

Here is a Marker I have

```
final Marker d1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(Driver1)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.driver1))
                    .title(DName1)
    );
```

Here is the Click

```
    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            //shit for dialog goes here i think
            new AlertDialog.Builder(ibMap.this)
                    .setTitle(marker.getTitle())
                    .setMessage("This Message isnt important")
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.driver1)
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            }

                    )
                    .setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(ibMap.this, checkout.class));
                                }
                            }

                    ).create().show();
```

Thanks

Comment: if you create array of images and set by position using marker.getId()  using.It may be Help.

Answer (score 0):

Markers may define a custom image to show in place of the default icon. Defining an icon involves setting a number of properties that affect the visual behavior of the marker.

You can replace the default marker image with a [custom marker image,](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#customize_the_marker_image) often called an icon. Custom icons are always set as a BitmapDescriptor, and defined using one of four methods in the BitmapDescriptorFactory class.

The below snippet creates a marker with a custom icon.

```
  private static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.813, 144.962);
  private Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(MELBOURNE)
                            .title("Melbourne")
                            .snippet("Population: 4,137,400")
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow)));
```

Here is a sample [javascript code,](https://jsfiddle.net/sc5jjjae/3/) I don't know if this is what you want.

I hope that it can help you.